# How to get rid of lines in colspan/rowspan cell of table?

Tags: html-table, border

I am trying to recreate something close to this table:

[image]

I am getting weird lines, though, with the way that I've gone about trying to do it. How do I get rid of them? Or could someone tell me the easiest way to achieve what is done in the table pictured above? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment #4</title>
<style>

table
    {
font-family:"Courier New", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse:collapse;
margin: auto;
border-bottom-style: double; border-top-style: double;

     }



table.border tr {border: 1px solid black; border-left: 0px solid; 
    border-right: 0px       solid;}

th
    {
font-size:18px;
font-style: bold;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
background-color:lightblue;
color:#000000;


    }



    tr.white td 
    {
color:#000000;
background-color: #ffffff;
    }

td,th
    {
font-size:1em;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
text-align: left;





</style>
</head>

<body>


    <body>

<h3 style="text-align: center; font-family: courier new;">
<strong>Code-page support in   microsoft windows</strong></h3>

<table class="border">
<tr>
  <th>Code-Page ID</th>
  <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Name</th>
  <th colspan="2">ACP OEMCP</th>
</tr
 <div>
<tr class="white">
    <td style="background-color: lightblue;" rowspan="3">1200 
        <br/>1250       
        <br/>1251</td>

    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" rowspan="3">Unicode 
      <br/>Windows 3.1 Eastern European 

      <br/>Windows 3.1 Cynillic</td>

    <td rowspan="3"><br/>X <br/>X</td>

</tr>

<tr class="white">

<td style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>


</tr>


<tr class="white">

<td style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>


</tr>

   </div>

<div>
<tr class="white">
<td style="background-color: lightblue;" rowspan="3">437 <br/>708 <br/>709</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;" rowspan="3">MS-DOS 
<br/>Arabic (ASMO 708)   
<br/>Arabic (ASMO 449)</td>
<td><br/></td>
<td colspan="2">X <br/>X <br/>X</td>
</tr>

<tr class="white">

<td style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>

</tr>

<tr class="white">

<td style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>

</tr>

</div>

<div>
<tr class="white">
<td style="background-color: lightblue;">Assignment#4</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">
<a href="http://www.mansfield.edu">Mansfield University</a></td>
<td colspan="2"><center>
<img src="http://mansfield.edu/files/images/Facebook.gif">  </center></td>
</tr>

</div>

</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the link of the image sample didn't work here for me :(

But if you mean the vertical lines like line1|line2 are your problem, you can use colspan=2. This will result in something like line1 line2.

Example:

```
<tr>
```

`<td colspan=2>`
`</td>`
`<td>`
`</td>`
`</tr>`

Hope that will help,

Regards,

Otacon

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess! You put two "body" and forgot some "}" and ">".
Apart that the problem was the "td's" in blank that you put inside the "tr". Here you have the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment #4</title>
<style>

table {
font-family:"Courier New", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse:collapse;
margin: auto;
border-bottom-style: double; border-top-style: double;
}



table.border tr {
    border: 1px solid black; 
    border-left: 0px solid; 
    border-right: 0px solid;
}

th{
font-size:18px;
font-style: bold;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
background-color:lightblue;
color:#000000;
}

tr.white td {
    color:#000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

td,th{
font-size:1em;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
text-align: left;
}




</style>
</head>

<body>

<h3 style="text-align: center; font-family: courier new;">
<strong>Code-page support in   microsoft windows</strong></h3>

<table class="border">
<tr>
  <th>Code-Page ID</th>
  <th style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center;">Name</th>
  <th colspan="2">ACP OEMCP</th>
</tr>
<tr class="white">
    <td style="background-color: lightblue;" rowspan="3">1200 
        <br/>1250       
        <br/>1251</td>

    <td style="border: 1px solid black;" rowspan="3">Unicode 
      <br/>Windows 3.1 Eastern European 

      <br/>Windows 3.1 Cynillic</td>

    <td rowspan="3"><br/>X <br/>X</td>

</tr>

<tr class="white">


</tr>


<tr class="white">


</tr>
<tr class="white">
<td style="background-color: lightblue;" rowspan="3">437 <br/>708 <br/>709</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;" rowspan="3">MS-DOS 
<br/>Arabic (ASMO 708)   
<br/>Arabic (ASMO 449)</td>
<td><br/></td>
<td colspan="2">X <br/>X <br/>X</td>
</tr>

<tr class="white">

</tr>

<tr class="white">

</tr>
<tr class="white">
<td style="background-color: lightblue;">Assignment#4</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">
<a href="http://www.mansfield.edu">Mansfield University</a></td>
<td colspan="2"><center>
<img src="http://mansfield.edu/files/images/Facebook.gif">  </center></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that's what you're looking for.
Hope this answer helped you.

Regards,
LGhost